# qmake project with app and tests target

Tags: c++, qt, qmake

can someone hint me how should I configure qmake to build app and tests executables separately?
I have read that i need to use "subdirs" template but i cant make it work. So i have this dir tree:

```
myProject
-myProject.pro
-app
 -app.pro
 -main.cpp
 -source
-test
  -test.pro
  -main.cpp
  -source
```

How do i configure .pro files? Can i somehow configure common settings in myProject.pro (add source files etc) and make app.pro and test.pro use this config (plus add something more)?

Comment: The standard way is to create *.pri files. These files follow the same rules as pro files and just include them in the appropriate pro files. Example : include(../mysettings.pri). If you give "include"  the right path to the pri file Qt Creator will parse that pri file as well.